# is there a function in woocommerce to get email attachment download link

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, download, email-attachments

I am a WordPress developer and using woocomerce hook **woocommerce_email_attachments** to attach a file with completed order email
This works fine , it attaches the required file

But I want to get that downloadable link of particular attachment , so i could use it in the email template anywhere instead of having it at the bottom of the email
(So when user clicks the link it should download that attachment)

I tried reading so many woocommerce classes but unfortunately couldn't find any function that returns the download link of attachment

Thank You

Comment: The path will be something like: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/test.pdf. But since your question does not contain a code but only a description, nobody can really know where the attachment is located on your website (in which folder/the file name). What you're asking doesn't actually exist but you could add it yourself via custom code. Please add the code that you are currently using via the `woocommerce_email_attachments` hook, so that your question contains  [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just read your comment dear , Thank you so much for helping me 
but I had done it yesterday, Actually i was getting the path string from a function of woocommerce appointment plugin which wasn't the right path , so i had to explode that string and and then remake that string and yes you are right the path was actually wp-content/uploads/2022/04/someFile.ics

Once again Thank you